# adding invisible recaptcha to ps_emailsubscription in the classic theme in prestashop 8.0.4

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, invisible-recaptcha, prestashop-modules

​
Hi

I'm plauged by spam from the ps_emailsubscription module.

the module is modified by and part of the classic theme. I have created a child theme off the classic theme. I'm changing the file:
my_child_classic_theme\modules\ps_emailsubscription\views\templates\hook\ps_emailsubscription.tpl

I've added this script the the end of the footer.tpl for the site (my_child_classic_theme\templates_partials\footer.tpl)

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

I've modified the ps_emailsubscription.tpl like so:

```
<div class="block_newsletter col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="blockEmailSubscription_{$hookName}">
  <div class="row">
    <p id="block-newsletter-label" class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">{l s='Get our latest news and special sales' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</p>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
      <div class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="MY_reCaptchaV2-Invisible-SITEKEY_HERE"
        data-callback="onSubmit"
        data-size="invisible">
      </div>
      <form id="ps_EmailSubscription" action="{$urls.current_url}#blockEmailSubscription_{$hookName}" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input
              class="btn btn-primary float-xs-right hidden-xs-down"
              name="submitNewsletter"
              type="button"
              value="{l s='Subscribe' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}"
              onclick="validateForm();"
            >
            <input
              class="btn btn-primary float-xs-right hidden-sm-up"
              name="submitNewsletter"
              type="submit"
              value="{l s='OK' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}"
            >
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input
                name="email"
                type="email"
                value="{$value}"
                placeholder="{l s='Your email address' d='Shop.Forms.Labels'}"
                aria-labelledby="block-newsletter-label"
                required
              >
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="blockHookName" value="{$hookName}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="0">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              {if $conditions}
                <p>{$conditions}</p>
              {/if}
              {if $msg}
                <p class="alert {if $nw_error}alert-danger{else}alert-success{/if}">
                  {$msg}
                </p>
              {/if}
              {hook h='displayNewsletterRegistration'}
              {if isset($id_module)}
                {hook h='displayGDPRConsent' id_module=$id_module}
              {/if}
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        console.log('Enter validateForm!');
        grecaptcha.execute();
        console.log('After grecaptcha.execute()!');
    }
    
    function onSubmit(token) {
        console.log('Enter onSubmit!');
        document.getElementById("ps_EmailSubscription").submit();
        console.log('After submit!');
    }
</script>
```

It is not working as expected, the onSubmit() causes a page refresh, and nothing else happens. The reCaptcha seems to work fine, as I see the recaptcha "hiding" in the lower right corner, and I've seen the (select all fields with XXXX) on pushing the input button, and in the callback i see the onSubmit being called.

but the basic validation that happens in the module (empty string, malformed email) is not working, nor is "email address allready exists", or any success message, and all the other functions of the original form, seems not to happen when pressing my input of type button.

if i add a line (basically another input that is visible):
`<input name="submitNewsletter" type="submit" value="{l s='Subscribe' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}">`

I can see all the form function are still working.

Im not used to developing in prestashop. So I could really need som help on whats wrong with my approach.

I hope somebody can help me.

/OhmegaStar